DiscordJS Collector don´t Collect Message V14

require('dotenv').config();
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
intents: [
GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
],
});
client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
client.on('ready', () => {
console.log("Bot has logged in.");
});
client.on('message', async message => {
if(message.author.bot) return;
if(message.content.toLowerCase() === '?listen') {
message.channel.send('bot is collecting messages now...');
let filter = m => !m.author.bot;
let collector = new discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, filter);
let destination = client.channels.get('1235316261081190491');
collector.on('collect', (m, col) => {
console.log("Collected message: " + m.content);
if(destination) {
if(m.content.toLowerCase() === '?stop' && (message.author.id === m.author.id)) {
console.log("Stopping collector.");
collector.stop();
}
else {
let embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
.setTitle("New Message")
.setDescription(m.content)
.setTimestamp()
.setAuthor(m.author.tag, m.author.displayAvatarURL)
.setColor('#FFAB32')
destination.send(embed);
}
}
});
collector.on('end', collected => {
console.log("Messages collected: " + collected.size);
}

});
as you can see from CMD pic when I typed ?listen on Discord channel there is nothing happen.
CMD
any one could help ?

I would like to get messages from discord channel when user using command, thank you in advance for helping me

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Have you enabled the message content intent on your application page?
